# Question on solving for conditional mean and conditional variance as well as solving for the conditional distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

I was just wondering if someone could walk me through the thought process of approaching this problem I was given in a lecture. The problem is "Given X = x, Y is defined in the following way: Y = x+W, where W
follows Normal distribution with mean zero and variance one. What is the
conditional mean and variance of Y given X = x. What is the conditional
distribution. Find variance of Y ." How do I go about solving for each of the values being asked for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating the distribution and its moments conditional on $X$ you should treat $X$ as a known constant.

So if, $W \sim N(0,1)$ it follows that $x+W|x \sim N(x,1).$

I used the following facts:

1. A normally distributed variable plus a constant is still normally distributed;
2. $\mathbb E[W+x]=\mathbb E[W]+x$, if $x$ is a constant; and
3. $\operatorname{Var}(W+x)=\operatorname{Var}(W)$, if $x$ is a constant.